# use k8s deepcopy-gen generate code failed

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am going to use k8s code-generator to generator deepcopy file and my project under `GOPATH/src`, but i seems not work and got a problem about GOROOT.

deepcopy-gen command is `deepcopy-gen -i k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis -p k8s_customize_controller/pkg/client -v 10`

output blow:

```sh
[root@centos72-k8s code-generator]# deepcopy-gen -i k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis -p k8s_customize_controller/pkg/client -v 10
I0122 02:51:04.609157   17278 parse.go:383] importPackage k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis
I0122 02:51:04.609359   17278 parse.go:330] addDir k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis
I0122 02:51:04.730397   17278 parse.go:404] unable to import "k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis": package k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis)
I0122 02:51:04.730701   17278 main.go:82] Completed successfully.
```

`unable to import "k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis": package k8s_customize_controller/pkg/apis is not in GOROOT`
it seems this problem about GOROOT?

how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with an error like this:

*Generating deepcopy funcs
F1018 10:51:28.259741   74132 main.go:80] Error: Failed making a parser: unable to add directory "github.com/[my-git-account]/[repo-name]/pkg/apis/v1": No files for pkg "github.com/[my-git-account]/[repo-name]/pkg/apis/v1"*

The problem was that I recently moved my github golang projects folders out of the `$GOPATH/src` folder (which is in my case is `~/go/src`), because it worked well on vanilla Ubuntu and WSL Ubuntu, but it has challenges to update packages on MacOS - I moved all my project from the folder `~/go/src/github.com/[my-git-account]`
(where the `code-generator` expected them) to the folder `~/dev/[my-git-account]`.

Solution I use to fix the error above - to create a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) on my current github projects folder to the `$GOPATH/src/github.com`:

```
ln -s ~/dev/[my-git-account] $GOPATH/src/github.com
```

This way there is a folder `$GOPATH/src/github.com/[my-git-account]` (provided by the sym-link) with golang projects, where `code-generator` can find them.

Faced one drawback of this trick - in the IDE navigation to the method can move to the linked source (within SDK package by the link - not to the source code, opened in the IDE).